# boost::asio vs. libpcap: avoid calling close twice

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, pcap

When running `strace` on the following program:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <pcap.h>

using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    asio::io_service io;
    asio::posix::stream_descriptor stream(io);
    char errorBuffer[BUFSIZ];
    pcap_t* p = pcap_open_live("any", BUFSIZ, false, 0, errorBuffer);
    stream.assign(pcap_get_selectable_fd(p));
    io.run();
    stream.close();
    pcap_close(p);
    return 0;
}
```

I get:

```
close(6)                                = 0
setsockopt(6, SOL_PACKET, PACKET_RX_RING, {block_size=0, block_nr=0, frame_size=0, frame_nr=0}, 16) = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
munmap(0xb733c000, 4145152)             = 0
close(6)                                = -1 EBADF (Bad file descriptor)
```

As you can see, `close` is called twice on the same `fd` (first by `stream.close()`, then by `pcap_close(p)`). While the program might not make sense, I need to call both `stream.close()` (to prevent `io_service` from calling `epoll_ctl` on a closed `fd`) and `pcap_close(p)` (to release the memory used by the `pcap_t`) - this happens on a multithreaded program.

Any ideas on how to do this without calling `close` on the same `fd` twice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `posix::stream_descriptor` assumes ownership of the descriptor, it will close it when going out of scope. To resolve the double close, duplicate the descriptor before assigning with `dup()`.